# Infinite loop using WHILE even though condition is met in R

Tags: r, while-loop

I am trying to learn how to implement control structures such as FOR and while loops.

I created a function the simulates betting in a famous Brazilian lotto.
In the lotto, a player bets on 6 unique integers from a 1:60 vector (called your_bet).
The function samples 6 values from the 1 to 60 universe ("result") and tests how many values in result match your_bet, printing out:

your_bet

result

total points (out of 6 possible)

one of three possible commentaries on the result of the bet.

Code as follows:

````
```

LOTTO<-function(your_bet=sample(1:60, size=6, replace=FALSE)){
    result<-sample(1:60, size=6, replace=FALSE)
    logical_vector<-(your_bet %in% result)
    total_points<-sum(as.integer(logical_vector))
    print(paste(c("Your bet:", as.character(your_bet))), collapse="")
    print(paste(c("Result", as.character(result))), collapse="")
    print(paste(c("Total points", as.character(total_points))), collapse="")
    if (total_points==6)
            print("You are a millonaire")
    else if (total_points==5)
            print("5 points, you are rich!")
    else print("good luck next time")
    }

```
````

I then tried to implement a loop that would make the function go over and over again in a loop until total points>= a given target (here as target_points), modifying the function as bellow.

````
```

LOTTO<-function(your_bet=sample(1:60, size=6, replace=FALSE), stubborn_until_x_points=FALSE, 
target_points)#inserted stubborn_until_x_points and target_points arguments{
    result<-sample(1:60, size=6, replace=FALSE)
    logical_vector<-(your_bet %in% result)
    total_points<-sum(as.integer(logical_vector))
    print(paste(c("Your bet:", as.character(your_bet))), collapse="")
    print(paste(c("Result", as.character(result))), collapse="")
    print(paste(c("Total points", as.character(total_points))), collapse="")
    if (total_points==6)
            print("You are a millonaire")
    else if (total_points==5)
            print("5 points, you are rich!")
    else print("good luck next time")
    if (stubborn_until_x_points==TRUE)#Inserted WHILE loop here{
            while(total_points < target_points){
                    LOTTO(your_bet, stubborn_until_x_points=TRUE, target_points)}
    }
}

```
````

This did make the function repeat in a loop, but for some reason, it keeps looping even when the condition is met.

Observation - I realized that when the condition is met on the first run, it actually stops, but after entering a loop, it goes on forever.

I can´t find what is wrong. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are not updating the total_points inside the loop

Comment: A friendly comment. This function has some unnecessary recursion. It would be more efficient (and C-stack-safe)  to encase all the code within your `while` loop. Simply start by defining `total_points <- -Inf` and `target_points <- Inf` and use `if(stubborn_until_x_points != TRUE)break` to test for early breaking. The limit to recursion in `R` is often rather restrictive so for functions that might reach quite some depth, it **can** make sense to remove recursion.

Comment: How could i do it? Could you show me? @rootkonda

Comment: If target_points is greater than 60 then also it would be in infinite loop isnt it ? did you check that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't dug quite deep into the function, but the only reason that this should not `break` at any point is when `target_points > n_samples` (6 here).

The problem in this case is quite obvious and simple to fix. Reduce `target_points` to be less than `6` or add `n_samples` (6 atm.) and make it greater than `target_points`. Rather than this I suspect the main problem lies within the recursive function though. `R` is rather restrictive when it comes to recursion, if one tries to do a simple recursion for example

```
i <- 0
f <- function(){
  i <<- i + 1
  f()
}
f()
i
# 896 on my pc
```

one can see that we cannot use recursion for very deep recursive functions (in R). This throws the very unhelpful error

> Error: C stack usage 7974196 is too close to the limit

To alleviate this, one *simply* has to remove the recursion (simply in italian because sometimes it is not simple). In this case we just move the `while` loop to contain the main body of the function, and use an `if` statement to break early if necessary.

Below is a slightly modified version of the function (note that `sample_n` and `number_range` has been added as arguments).
In this function the `while` loop has been moved to contain the main body, and the result is instead printed at the end (using the variable `res` to figure out the result). At the end of the loop I use a `if(isFALSE(stubborn_until_x_points))break` statement to exit early if necessary.

```
LOTTO <- function(your_bet, 
                  sample_n = 6, 
                  number_range = 1:60,
                  stubborn_until_x_points = FALSE, 
                  target_points){
  if(missing(target_points) || target_points > sample_n) 
    stop('missing target_points or target_points too large')
  total_points <- -Inf # Always smaller than target_points
  i <- 0
  res <- 0
  # If you want a new bet every iteration.
  # Add this at the end of the loop, but remove the 'if' 
  if(missing(your_bet)) 
    your_bet <- sample(number_range, size=sample_n, replace=FALSE)
  while(total_points < target_points){
    result <- sample(number_range, size=sample_n, replace=FALSE)
    logical_vector <- your_bet %in% result
    total_points <- sum(logical_vector)
    if (total_points==6){
      res <- 1
    }else if (total_points==5){
      res <- 2
    }
    i <- i + 1
    if(isFALSE(stubborn_until_x_points))
      break
  }
  if(res == 1)
    cat(res <- 'You\'re a millionaire!\n', sep = '\n')
  else if(res == 2)
    cat(res <- '5  points, you are rich!\n', sep = '\n')
  else 
    cat(res <- 'Better luck next time.', sep = '\n')
  c(result = res, number_of_tries = i)
}
```

The function is called as before, but now also returns the number of attempts and the result obtained from trials as shown below.

```
LOTTO(target_points = 6, stubborn_until_x_points = TRUE)
You're a millionaire!
#Output:
                   result           number_of_tries 
"You're a millionaire!\n"                 "8297820"
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing recursion, including the body of the function inside the while loop, assigning -Inf to the initial total_points and adding the break statement were much usefull.
Addapting the answer by @Oliver yielded exactly what I was looking for:

```
LOTTO<-function(your_bet=sample(1:60, size=6, replace=FALSE), stubborn_until_x_points=FALSE, 
                target_points=0){
        total_points<--Inf
        while(total_points < target_points){
        result<-sample(1:60, size=6, replace=FALSE)
        logical_vector<-(your_bet %in% result)
        total_points<-sum(as.integer(logical_vector))
        print(paste(c("Your bet:", as.character(your_bet))), collapse="")
        print(paste(c("Result", as.character(result))), collapse="")
        print(paste(c("Total points", as.character(total_points))), collapse="")
        if (total_points==6)
                print("You are a millonaire")
        else if (total_points==5)
                print("5 points, you are rich!")
        else print("good luck next time")
        if (isFALSE(stubborn_until_x_points==TRUE))
                break
                
        }
```

His answer, however, yields interesting additional results, and better control over inadequate argument inputs